# JavaScriptSerializer in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, javascriptserializer

My ASP.NET MVC project references System.Web.Extensions, however the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace is not available, it should according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The assembly's version is 3.5.0.0, however the Runtime Version is v2.0.50727, will this be the issue? I'm trying to use the JavaScriptSerializer class in asp.net 3.5

Comment: .NET 3.5 uses runtime version 2.0 so there is no problem with that. Can you open the assembly with Reflector for example and check whether it contains the method?

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to your project to "System.Web.Extensions.dll"

Then use:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

[Quick JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c)